# Calc 3 - Vector Valued Function Initial Value Problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, initial-value-problems

The starting position of a particle is given by
$\mathbf p(0)=\langle 5,−2\rangle$

Suppose the initial velocity is given by $\mathbf v(0)=\langle 1,2\rangle$ and the acceleration is given by $\mathbf a(t)=\langle 2,3\rangle$. Find: the velocity function, $\mathbf f(t)$ (a vector), the speed function $s(t)$, and the position function $\mathbf p(t)$ (a vector).

I'm not really sure how to use the information given in this problem! Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you not sure? What is the definition of velocity and what is the definition of acceleration?

Comment: Could you solve the problem in 1 dimension? The whole thing about linear algebra is that the dimensions are all separate. That's the point of the concept of 'basis,' that we can break things down into individual pieces. If you could solve it in 1 dimension, then do the same thing you do in one dimension in each dimension and put it together.

Comment: @AlfredYerger: Most likely, this calculus student doesn't know any of the linear algebra language.

Comment: @TedShifrin :( At least the moral is the same - you can solve it in each part and just put them together.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put it like this: $$ a(t) = \begin{bmatrix}a_1(t)\\a_2(t)\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}v_1'(t)\\v_2'(t)\end{bmatrix} $$
So we integrate *each component* to get: $$ v(t)=\int a(t)\,dt = \int \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} dt = \begin{bmatrix} 2t +c_1 \\ 3t+c_2 \end{bmatrix} $$
The initial conditions then say $$ v(0) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 2(0) +c_1 \\ 3(0)+c_2 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix}\;\;\;\implies\;\;\; v(t)=\begin{bmatrix} 2t +1 \\ 3t+2 \end{bmatrix}$$ So the speed function is then: $$ s(t) = ||v(t)||_2 = \sqrt{(2t+1)^2+(3t+2)^2} = \sqrt{13t^2+16t+5} $$
The position function is basically the same:
$$ p(t) = \int v(t)\,dt = \int \begin{bmatrix} 2t +1 \\ 3t+2 \end{bmatrix}dt = \begin{bmatrix} t^2 +t+k_1 \\ 3t^2/2+2t+k_2 \end{bmatrix} $$
And again, the initial conditions: $$ p(0) = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} k_1 \\ k_2 \end{bmatrix}\;\;\;\implies\;\;\; p(t)= \begin{bmatrix} t^2 +t+5 \\ 3t^2/2+2t-2 \end{bmatrix} $$